# What is faster to search in hashmap/object or array in mongodb?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object

We have 3 entities.
**Article**
**Note**
**Comment**

Article can have 0 or many Notes and Note can have 0 or many Comments

**Our actions**
1. We want to fetch from db single Note by Note id
2. We want to add new Note to Article
3. We want to add new comment to Note

**Scheme 1**

```
{
    _id: 'article_1',
    name: "Article 1",
    notes: [{
        _id: 'note_1',
        name: 'Note 1',
        comments: [{
            content: 'Hello World'
        }]
    }]
}
```

**Approach 1**
1. `db.Article.find({_id: 'article_1', 'notes._id': 'note_1'}, {'notes.$': 1})`
2. `db.Article.update({_id: 'article_1'}, {$push: {notes: {_id: 'note_2', name: 'note2'}}})`
3. `db.Article.update({_id: 'article_1', 'notes._id': 'note_2'}, {$push: {'notes.$.comments': {content: 'Hi !!!'}}})`

**Scheme 2**

```
{
    _id: 'article_2',
    name: "Article 2",
    notes: {
        'note_1': {
            name: 'Note 1',
            comments: [{
                content: 'Hello World'
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

**Approach 2**
1. `db.Article.find({_id: 'article_2'}, {'notes.note_1':1})`
2. `db.Article.update({_id: 'article_2'}, {$set: {'notes.note_2': {name: 'note2'}}})`
3. `db.Article.update({_id: 'article_2'}, {$push: {'notes.note_2.comments': {content: 'Hi !!!'}}})`

Which scheme and approach is considered to be best practice and which for better performace and why.
Thank you

Comment: Have you considered put `notes` on a separate collection? With this current schema, if a particular article grows too large in document size, every time an user enter a new comment, MongoDB will call the entire document back in memory. Not to say if your app client will need to transfer the entire document thru the network, and potential slow queries on the server.